# altinity clickhouse operator config max_memory usage value

Tags: clickhouse

I deployed altinity clickhouse-operator 0.20.3 on my local kubernetes cluster following by altinity official deploy instuction. Because of the huge data I stored (about 15 billion records) in clickhouse, I need to change users.xml config file parameter max_memory_usage for making group by query doesn't raise MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error.

How could I change this value while deploying clickhouse cluster?

I added some config into chi resource like below.

```
apiVersion: clickhouse.altinity.com/v1
kind: ClickHouseInstallation
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      ...
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-10T08:56:39Z"
  finalizers:
  - finalizer.clickhouseinstallation.altinity.com
  generation: 10
  name: ch-cluster
  namespace: clickhouse
  resourceVersion: "27275038"
  uid: 2506b554-6eda-4826-a03c-234faf9fd737
spec:
  configuration:
    clusters:
    - layout:
        replicasCount: 1
        shardsCount: 5
      name: ch-cluster
      templates:
        podTemplate: clickhouse-stable
        volumeClaimTemplate: storage-vc-template
    profiles:
      default/max_memory_usage: "100000000000"
      default/max_memory_usage_for_user: "100000000000"
      max_bytes_before_external_group_by: "100000000000"
      readonly/readonly: "1"
      use_uncompressed_cache: 0
```

After that the max_memory_usage value is still 10Gi as before, I checked it in the pods.

Please help me about how to config the value in ClickHouseInstallation yaml. Or is there anothor way to make it work?

Comment: max_bytes_before_external_group_by also should be under default